# State Variables become null When UseEffect hook is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make new requests whenever user reach the bottom with the following;

```
useEffect(() => {
    const scrolling_function = () => {
      if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight-10){
        window.removeEventListener('scroll',scrolling_function)
        getMoviesFromApi()
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrolling_function);
}, [])
```

But the state objects that I defined, such as:

```
const[selectedGenres, setSelectedGenres] = useState(new Set())
```

All becomes undefined in the inside of my `useEffect` hook, and thus my `getMoviesFromApi()` method does not work properly.

My question is, is that expected behavior? If so, how could I overcome it?

The `getmoviesfromapi` method:

```
const getMoviesFromApi = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    let init, end;
    if(initialYear>endYear) {
      init = endYear
      end = initialYear
    } else {
      init = initialYear
      end = endYear
    }
    let res =await fetchMovies(init, end)
    setLoading(false)
    setMovies(res.results)
  }
```

The `fetchMovies` method:

```
const fetchMovies = async (startYear, endYear) => {
    let res;

    res = [];
    let genreQuery = "";
    let serviceQuery = "";
    for (let it = selectedGenres.values(), val= null; val=it.next().value; ) {
      genreQuery += "&genre=" + val;
    }
    for (let it = selectedServices.values(), val= null; val=it.next().value; ) {
      serviceQuery += "&service=" + val;
    }

    let countryQuery = "?country="+country;
    let yearQuery = "&year_min="+ startYear +"&year_max=" + endYear;
    let typeQuery = "&type=" + (isMovie ? "movie" : "series");
    let url = api_url + countryQuery + serviceQuery + typeQuery +"&order_by=year" + yearQuery
          + genreQuery + "&page=1&desc=true&language=en&output_language=en"

    await fetch(url, {
      "method": "GET",
    }).then(response => {
          res= response.json()
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    return res;
  };
```

Comment: what's the code of `getMoviesFromApi`? where is that defined?

Comment: show the whole component, we can't tell with just this much code. Also, you need to return a "clean up" function in your useEffect hook that also removes that event listener.

Comment: @TJBlackman thank you for the comment. I figured out I should add state objects or functions as dependencies and define functions with useCallBack(), which resolved my problem. However, the fetch method is called more than one time, which may be related to that cleanup function?  Can you elaborate more about that?

Comment: @TJBlackman nvm , got it, a return  function with removing event listener, just like you said :d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the necessary state objects and functions to the dependencies, and call the functions with useCallBack. You can be sure that you're making it right by installing eslint-plugin-react-hooks as a dev dependency. You'd also need a cleanUp function for your effect hook.

```
useEffect( () =>{
    const scrolling_function = async () => {
      if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight-10){
        await getMoviesFromApi(false);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrolling_function);
    return function cleanUp() { //don't forget to clean up
      window.removeEventListener('scroll',scrolling_function);
    }
  }, [getMoviesFromApi]); //add method as dependency!

//...

const getMoviesFromApi = useCallback () => { //useCallBack is needed here!
   ...
}
```